# Issue while inserting a double value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I created a table.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` ( `duration` double(20,5) DEFAULT NULL);
```

when i insert a record.

```
insert into test(duration) values(1.4002860713999996E8);
```

it is getting insert in this way.

```
+-----------------+
| duration        |
+-----------------+
| 140028607.14000 |
```

where as 1.40029 is expected.Can anyone explain me the reason for this? How can i insert the exact value ?

Comment: Do you know what `E8` at the end means?

Answer (score 2):

The E in the 1.4002860713999996E8 is Exponent, Which means 1.40002...*10^8 , That's why you are getting the inserted value as 140028607.14000

If you want to save the exact same value, I would say use VARCHAR to store the data, and you can typecast it to double when using it, Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

`E8` in the end means that

```
1.4002860713999996E8 = 1.4002860713999996 * 10^8 = 
   1.4002860713999996 * 100000000 = 140028607.13999996.
```

As soon it is `double(20,5)` then MySQL performs rounding when storing value to leave only 5 digits after decimal point and we get `140028607.14000`

Answer (score 0):

It is returning the correct result as while inserting your using exponential form of data.

E8 in     1.4002860713999996E8 means `1.4002860713999996E8` into 10 to the power 8.